# Online English dictionaries which group words with identical roots together

Tags: dictionaries

I am wondering whether there are out there online English dictionaries which group words with identical roots together to simplify learning.

For example when I learn verb "subdue" it would be great to know immediately that the related noun is "subdual", and probably there is an adjective which I do not know yet.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sardonic) does list related words together (e.g. in the case of [sardonic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sardonic) it also let me know about sardonically) but not in all cases (e.g. in the case of [purpose](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/purpose) no mention of purposive can be found).

Comment: Many dictionaries will give related words, but none gives *all* related words. A word like **purposive** is not in general use; it is used in philosophical and legal discourse and in other academic contexts. For that reason you're not likely to find it among the related words for the **purpose** entry.  But if you understand what the suffix **ive** does, and you understand what the word **purpose** means, you would probably be able to deduce the meaning of the word **purposive** upon encountering it.

Comment: What @Tᴚoɯɐuo said. Moreover, the more common related word for _purpose_ would be [_purposeful_](http://wordnik.com/words/purposeful). But it's very difficult to list all related words. For example, using _purpose_, we could have _purposes, unpurposeful, unpurposefully,_ etc. But some of those are in such limited use dictionaries don't bother to list them.

Comment: Isn't this called "derivative thesaurus"?

Comment: @drabsv Are you aware of any online or offline ones?

Comment: @ Sergey Zykov I think http://www.sequencepublishing.com/thesage/thesage.html ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the wildcard feature on [OneLook](https://onelook.com/).

Typing `*purpose*` into OneLook's main window yields [13 common word results](https://onelook.com/?w=*purpose*&scwo=1&sswo=1), but when you change the filter include **all** words and phrases, you'll find there are [hundreds](https://onelook.com/?w=*purpose*&ssbp=1). (Even though most of these are phrases, it still underscores the impracticality of listing all variants beneath each word in a dictionary – particularly a print dictionary.)

But even OneLook's lengthy compendium is imcomplete; words can be coined as needed. I leave you this quote:

> I describe a literary field organized around purposeful novels, she describes a literary field organized around didactic poetry. In both of our accounts, the literary field is profoundly altered at century's end — by what I call **antipurposeful** aestheticism and protomodernism and what Loeffelholz calls antididactic aestheticism. <sub>([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=HjXPUv4tOJ0C))</sub>

It's better to learn how prefixes and suffixes work than to try to study a particular word's valid forms.